# how do i make the brush single?

Tags: sculpting

my brush on the sculpting menu every time i try to sculpt it makes a copy on the other side. i just want it to be single
[image]

as you can see you have the circle with the dot telling you were the mouse is to draw. but there's a secondary dot.

how do i get rid of it so i can make a single sculpt without it duplicating on the other side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mirror. In tool settings deactivate this option by pressing button X:

[image]

If you haven't this toolbar, enable it in menu View -> Tool Settings

[image]